# Creating a generic builder pattern for classes with no parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, generics, builder

We are attempting to implement the builder pattern in an extensible way that does not rely on our devs coding the builder directly using the common `With` pattern (i.e. every public field has a `WithX(...)` method on the builder).

We have seen a potential pattern that uses lambda expressions to change reduce the builder to a common `With` function that then applies the lambdas on the invocation of the `Build` call.

However, all the implementation of such a pattern expect the object being created should have a parameterless constructor and public setters.

The objects we are attempting to build do no have neither public setters nor parameterless constructors.

For example, our classes look like:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int field { get; }

    public Class1(int field)
    {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

Our builder would normally be:

```
public class Class1Builder
{
    private int _field;

    public Class1Builder()
    {
        this._field = 1;
    }

    public Class1Builder WithField(int field)
    {
        _field = field;
        return this;
    }

    public Class1 Build()
    {
        return new Class1(_field);
    }
}
```

We would like to convert it `With` method to something that could allow the usage of:

```
var class1 = new Class1Builder.With(x => x.Field = 3).Build();
```

Is there a way of doing such a thing?